# Ambiguity in c++ constructor when a constructor with default argument exists

Tags: c++, constructor

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class abc{
    int a;
   public: abc() { } //do nothing constructor
           abc(int x=6){ a=x;} //constructor with default argument  
  };
 main()
  {
      abc a;
    ....
  }
```

my question is which constructor will be invoked in this case ? Please explain

Comment: It will fail to compile because, it's ambiguous call

Comment: It will also fail to compile because the declaration of main is invalid. Your compiler should have told you both of these things.

Comment: How long would it take to test this code on an ide, say ideone.com ?  http://ideone.com/6qcSNU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not compile due to the ambiguity as you can see [here](http://ideone.com/OWZWWj)

```
prog.cpp:8:7: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type [-Wreturn-type]
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:10:11: error: call of overloaded ‘abc()’ is ambiguous
prog.cpp:10:11: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:6:12: note: abc::abc(int)
prog.cpp:5:12: note: abc::abc()
```

Answer (score 0):

The call you are making to the constructor is ambiguous. The compiler cannot know which constructor to call since one of your constructor contains a default argument.

Instead, try removing the default value to the argument.