# Why is call of overloaded 'function(std::string)' is ambiguous?

Tags: c++

The code is as below. Since the number of parameters is different, the call should not be ambiguous. One of the constructors accepts a string and other string plus integer. Why do I get the error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class AmbiguosCheck {

public:
AmbiguosCheck(string checkId = string(""),
int length = 0) :
checkId_(checkId),
length_(length){}

AmbiguosCheck(string xmlstring)
{
fromStringForInternalTransfer(xmlstring);
}

string checkId_;
int length_;

string toStringForInternalTransfer(){
return checkId_ + "|" + to_string(length_);
}

void fromStringForInternalTransfer(string xmlstring)
{
checkId_ = xmlstring; //Using simple assigment for sample code. Need to split, convert and assign the values.
length_ = 20;
}
};

int main()
{
AmbiguosCheck bd((string)"Check ID|20.000");
}
```

**Compilation error:**

```
In function 'int main()':  
35:44: error: call of overloaded 'AmbiguosCheck(std::string)' is ambiguous  
35:44: note: candidates are:  
14:5: note: AmbiguosCheck::AmbiguosCheck(std::string)  
9:5: note: AmbiguosCheck::AmbiguosCheck(std::string, int)  
6:7: note: AmbiguosCheck::AmbiguosCheck(const AmbiguosCheck&)  
6:7: note: AmbiguosCheck::AmbiguosCheck(AmbiguosCheck&&)
```

And why are there 2 more candidates for ambiguity?

Comment: You have two constructors that can take a single `std::string` argument (the one taking an `int` argument have both the `std::string` and `int` arguments as ***optional***). Which one should be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ambiguity in c++ constructor when a constructor with default argument exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770113/ambiguity-in-c-constructor-when-a-constructor-with-default-argument-exists)

Comment: I understand now, why I get the error. But I don't know how to solve this.  Because the meaning of string are different in the two function. In the case AmbiguosCheck(string, int) its direct assignment to member variable. And when AmbiguosCheck(xmlstring) I want to split the string and assign the value after converting them. I have not done that in the sample code.

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink the design that lead to this code? For example by creating a small inheritance hierarchy where you have two child-classes that implements one way each? Or perhaps implement some kind of factory function (or a pair of them) to create the object?

Comment: I will dig more then.

Answer (score 1):

The first constructor specifies a default value for the second `int` argument. This can hence be left out, which then leaves you with two constructors that both can be invoked with one `std::string` argument. This is indeed ambiguous.

To fix this, you can remove the `= 0` default parameter, by passing the integral second argument as a (non-defaulted) `std::optional<int>` (C++17 is required, then) or go with named static factory functions.

Comment: I understand now, why I get the error. But I don't know how to solve this. Because the meaning of string are different in the two function. In the case AmbiguosCheck(string, int) its direct assignment to member variable. And when AmbiguosCheck(xmlstring) I want to split the string and assign the value after converting them. I have not done that in the sample code.

Comment: Well, I tried to give you three options on how to fix that. Can you be specific about what part of those suggestions you don't understand?

Comment: I will give more context. What I wanted to do was to have two constructors. One which passes the values of class members to initialize the class members and the other which unpacks the values from a string. Right now I can do what I need to do by calling the default constructor and then calling the function fromStringForInternalTransfer. ` AmbiguosCheck bd; bd.fromStringForInternalTransfer("Check ID|20.000");` I wanted to do this directly in the constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

> AmbiguosCheck(string checkId = string(""),
>   int length = 0)
>      AmbiguosCheck(string xmlstring)

So if you have `AmbiguosCheck(myString)` which is it to call?

```
AmbiguosCheck(myString, 0); // first constructor, because length = 0 default
AmbiguosCheck(myString); // second single argument constructor
```

Does having the second constructor actually makes sense? If `length = 0` is a proper default, just keep that one.

Otherwise maybe get rid of the default values, and have a default constructor.

```
AmbiguosCheck() { ... }
AmbiguosCheck(string xmlstring) { ... }
AmbiguosCheck(string checkId, int length) { ... }
```

Which can all be called unambiguously.

```
AmbiguosCheck a; // default constructor ()
AmbiguosCheck b(myString); // string
AmbiguosCheck c(myString, n); // string, int
```

Comment: I understand now, why I get the error. But I don't know how to solve this.  Because the meaning of string are different in the two function. In the case AmbiguosCheck(string, int) its direct assignment to member variable. And when AmbiguosCheck(xmlstring) I want to split the string and assign the value after converting them. I have not done that in the sample code.

Comment: Well then use the form without default parameters, you will just have to do `AmbiguosCheck(myString, 0)` explicitly if you want the `int` version with a zero, but you need something explicit to tell them apart, the compiler can't guess from other context. An alternative that might be far less confusing would be ["named constructors"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom).